# How to preload native ads, android?

Tags: android, kotlin, admob, native-ads, google-ads-api

I added a single Native ad to my application, but on different devices, ads, especially videos, come with a delay, on the emulator the video is not shown at all. I know that you can somehow preload ads,
but I don’t know how to do it, please explain to me.

Here is my code:

```
class Fragment(private var index: Int, private var adsId: String) : Fragment() {

    var currentNativeAd: UnifiedNativeAd? = null
    lateinit var adLoader: AdLoader

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false)
        return view
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        val unifiedNativeAdView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.native_ad_layout, null) as UnifiedNativeAdView

        val nativeAdLayout = view!!.findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.id_native_ad)

        val adLoader = AdLoader.Builder(activity, adsId).forUnifiedNativeAd { unifiedNativeAd ->
(unifiedNativeAd)
            mapUnifiedNativeAdToLayout(unifiedNativeAd, unifiedNativeAdView)
            nativeAdLayout.removeAllViews()

        }.withAdListener(object : AdListener() {
            // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
            override fun onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded()
                if (!adLoader.isLoading) {
                  nativeAdLayout.addView(unifiedNativeAdView)
                }
            }

            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode: Int) {
               Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Ad failed to load! error code: $errorCode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onAdClosed() {
                nativeAdLayout.removeAllViews()

            }

        }).build()
        adLoader.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
   
    }

    fun mapUnifiedNativeAdToLayout(adFromGoogle: UnifiedNativeAd, myAdView: UnifiedNativeAdView) {
        currentNativeAd?.destroy()
        currentNativeAd = adFromGoogle

        val mediaView: MediaView = myAdView.findViewById(R.id.ad_media)
        myAdView.mediaView = mediaView
        myAdView.bodyView = myAdView.findViewById(R.id.ad_body)

        if (adFromGoogle.body == null) {
            myAdView.bodyView.visibility = View.GONE
        } else {
            (myAdView.bodyView as TextView).text = adFromGoogle.body
        }

        myAdView.setNativeAd(adFromGoogle)

        val vc = adFromGoogle.videoController

        if (vc.hasVideoContent()) {

            vc.videoLifecycleCallbacks = object : VideoController.VideoLifecycleCallbacks() {
                override fun onVideoEnd() {
                    super.onVideoEnd()
                }
            }
        } 
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        currentNativeAd?.destroy()
        super.onDestroy()

    }
}
```

native_ad_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.MediaView
                    android:id="@+id/ad_media"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:background="#fff" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ad_body"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/sf_pro_display_regular"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="body of ad"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    
    </LinearLayout>

</com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView>
```

In a fragment.xml, just a FrameView for the ad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using java there was a method that's on the google docs that mentions using adloader.isLoading

so in your

```
override fun onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded()

            }

you would ad if(!adLoader.isLoading){
    //insert ads to your recycler.
}
```

so..

```
    override fun onAdLoaded() {
                    super.onAdLoaded()
                   if(!adLoader.isLoading){

    int number_of_posts_before_showing_ad = 5

  if (nativeAds.size() <= 0 || yourPostList.size() < number_of_posts_before_showing_ad) {
            return;
        } else {
            int offset = (yourPostList.size() / nativeAds.size() + 1);
            int index = 0;
            for (UnifiedNativeAd ad : nativeAds) {
                yourPostList.add(index, ad);
                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                index += offset;
            }
        }
    }
    
                }
```

Comment: I have only one declaration, and yes, I understand why this method is needed, but I do not understand what exactly needs to be written in it.

Comment: I added the code I use from google docs that show how to load the ad. Basically the if statement says if there are no ads, and the number of posts are at least 5, load an ad. the for loop I'm assuming loops through available ads, and the offset and index is from google which is what is used to put an ad between posts at certain intervals